# On a Mac, where are FSRead, FSWrite, SetFPos et al defined, and should I even be using them?

Tags: macos, file-io, osx-snow-leopard

I'm an experienced Linux programmer, familiar with POSIX, stdio.h and so on, but totally new to Mac programming.  This week I'm attempting to get a piece of source code written by someone else a few years ago to work on 64-bit Snow Leopard.  It's a Photoshop plugin originally for CS3, now to be made to work with CS5.  (Don't ask me about CS4.)   This plugin is built at the command line with a handwritten makefile using gcc.

The main roadblock today is the compiler complaining about several undeclared functions: FSRead, FSWrite, SetFPos, GetFPos, and more, all having to do with files.  I'm pretty sure I have the right paths, options etc.

After two days grepping headers, googling, and trying to cheap hacks, I am stuck. Where are these functions defined?  Are they standard Mac OS X library functions, or Photoshop SDK functions?   Some google results suggest these functions are obsolete, "deprecated" but I guess by now truly gone.  If that's the case, what should I be using  instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After two days grepping headers, googling, and trying to cheap hacks, I am stuck. Where are these functions defined? Are they standard Mac OS X library functions, or Photoshop SDK functions?

They are old Carbon APIs. You can use the Carbon framework, however Carbon is not ported to 64-bit systems. As Photoshop is 64bit, this simply won't work.

I'm not familiar with how Photoshop plugins are handled, but if you are looking for a direct replacement you would look at [Core Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Foundation), a C API. In reality, you can also use the POSIX APIs. If Photoshop uses Cocoa and Objective-C, you can use the [Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_Kit) and AppKit family of APIs.

Comment: I'm hoping this will be an easy task of just hacking source modestly and recompiling.  It's in C, no GUI or anything just a C function to provide to Photoshop.  A ground-up rewrite using Obj-C might be called for eventually, but for now I'll try the CF.

Comment: Make sure to use the Core Foundation framework in your compiler invocation: -framework CoreFoundation