# Replacing Carbon file functions with stdio.h functions

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, stdio

I'm attempting to convert an old chunk of code containing the obsolete Carbon functions FSWrite, FSRead, etc.  One experiment we want to try is replacing these with their POSIX equivalents, the functions defined in stdio.h, e.g. replacing FSRead() with fread().   But I'm not sure what to do about the first arg given to the Carbon functions:

```
SetFPos(gFormatRecord->dataFork, fsFromStart, 0);
```

gFormatRecord is a pointer to a FormatRecord.  Is the dataFork just a plain regular unixy file handle suitable to shove into fread(), fprintf() and such?   (I don't know much about file "forks" in any case.)

(This is a follow-up to my earlier question, [On a Mac, where are FSRead, FSWrite, SetFPos et al defined, and should I even be using them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6514437/10468))

Comment: Btw, if this endeavor is foolish, that's ok; we suspect this whole thing needs a deeper rewrite anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `gFormatRecord->dataFork`, it sounds like you're trying to write a Photoshop plugin. That's not going to work so well.

Photoshop (and presumably most Mac Adobe software) is full of a *lot* of Carbon code, which was designed to be largely identical to existing 8.5 APIs while also being API/ABI compatible with OS X (I don't know if/when CFM Carbon support was dropped).

According to the documentation, you're supposed to use FSSetForkPosition() instead, which probably ends up being the same function call in the end. You almost certainly can't use `fseek()`/`fsetpos()`/`fseeko()`, which expect a `FILE *`, while a Carbon file handle appears to be a SInt16 according to my header (the webdocs say it's a FSIORefNum). [1]

Also note that `fopen()` and friends are not POSIX; they're standard C. The POSIX functions are generally the same without the leading f, except for seek which is `lseek()`. [2] The POSIX "file handle" is a file descriptor, which is just an `int`.

Now, if you're *incredibly* lucky, a FSIORefNum will just be a file descriptor which you can pass to `read()`/`write()`/`lseek()`. But this is ultimately for little benefit; if Photoshop's still built on Carbon, what's the point?

---

Footnotes!

1. It's not impossible that fseek() special-cases pointers to the zero page, but I don't think they'd pollute libc with that.)
2. On Linux/x86, you'll need to `#define __FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` or so to get largefile support, which is easy to forget. Shame it's not easy to do so universally...

Comment: Is what you say about fopen(), fread() etc just as true for open(), read() etc?

Comment: Of course not; one set takes a `FILE*` and the other takes an `int`. Whether they are compatible with the Carbon calls is anyone's guess (depending on how Carbon is implemented on OS X, they could be), but I really wouldn't rely on it in production code.